# SQL Concat Rows if duplicate ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to concat rows if there are duplicate IDs?

For example

```
ROOM_ID   LINE   ROOM_ADDRESS
001       1      100 Washington St
001       2      Unit 2
002       1      200 California St
003       1      150 Alabama St
003       2      Unit 1
```

If I were to `GROUP BY ROOM_ID` I would lose the information in Line 2. So is there a way to get the following results:

```
ROOM_ID   ROOM_ADDRESS
001       100 Washington St Unit 2
002       200 California St
003       150 Alabama St Unit 1
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are using SQL 2017 you can use STRING_AGG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only a handful of lines, then conditional aggregation might be the easiest method:

```
select room_id,
       (max(case when line = 1 then room_address else '' end) +
        max(case when line = 2 then ' ' + room_address else '' end) +
        max(case when line = 3 then ' ' + room_address else '' end)
       ) as room_address
from t
group by room_id;
```

Note that this does not generalize very well, but it works quite effectively for two or three addresses.

You can do something similar with `left join`:

```
select t1.room_id,
       (t1.address + coalesce(' ' + t2.address, '') + coalesce(' ' + t3.address, '')) as room_address
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.room_id = t2.room_id and t2.line = 2 left join
     t t3
     on t1.room_id = t3.room_id and t3.line = 3
where line = 1;
```